Docker Build Failing with "lstat /build: no such file or directory" — How to Ensure the Build Directory Exists?
I'm encountering an issue when running a Docker build in my CI pipeline. The build is failing with the following error:
ERROR: lstat /build: no such file or directory

Context:
The build process uses a Makefile to generate certain files (*example.txt) in a build directory, which are then copied over during the Docker build.
The Dockerfile has a COPY step that attempts to copy the *example.txt files from the /build directory into the image, but it fails because the directory is not found.
Dockerfile Snippet:
FROM python:3.12-slim as builder

WORKDIR /build

RUN python3 -m venv venv

COPY ./build/*example.txt .

RUN --mount=type=cache,target=$PIP_CACHE_DIR \
    . ./venv/bin/activate &&\
    pip3 -v install -r ./dbfolder-example.txt -r ./myfolder-example.txt

CI Pipeline (Azure DevOps YAML) Snippet:
  # Step 2: Build and Push MyImage using Docker Buildx
  - script: |
      docker buildx create --use || echo "Docker Buildx instance already exists."
      docker buildx build --file $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myimage/Dockerfile \
        --tag $(containerRegistry)/myimage:$(version) \
        --tag $(containerRegistry)/myimage:$(version)-$(buildVersion) \
        --build-context myfolder=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/myfolder \
        --push .
    displayName: 'Build and Push myimage Image with Buildx'

Makefile:
include ../subdir.mk

BUILD_NAME = myimage

BUILD_VERSION = latest

./build/myimage-example.txt: ./poetry.lock ./Makefile
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    poetry export --without-hashes --only main > $@

./poetry.lock: ./pyproject.toml
    poetry lock --no-update

./build/myfolder-example.txt: ../myfolder/poetry.lock
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    poetry -C ../myfolder export --without-hashes --only main > $@

../myfolder/poetry.lock: ../myfolder/pyproject.toml
    poetry -C ../myfolder lock --no-update

build-pre:: ./build/myimage-example.txt ./build/myfolder-example.txt

build:: build-pre
    $(BUILD) --tag $(BUILD_NAME):$(BUILD_VERSION) --file ./Dockerfile --build-context folder=../myfolder .
    docker image ls $(BUILD_NAME)

How can I ensure that the build directory and the *example.txt files are properly generated before Docker tries to copy them?

The requirements files should probably be checked into source control.  Outside this CI pipeline, where does the build directory come from, and do you have corresponding script lines to do the same thing?

to avoid any confusion, the file that I need is the example.txt file. The /build directory that contains the example.txt file is created with the Makefile

The example.txt file, as a lock file with a known-working list of specific Python library versions, is in source control, correct?  What runs make in this sequence?

I updated the question with the Make file. The example.txt file is not in the source control, it is generated by the make file using poetry

What calls make?  Can you directly invoke poetry instead of pip here?  If you're not actually using version locking, can you directly install whatever dependency constraints you have rather than trying to generate a (not fixed) lock file?

can you check the file creation in your makefile?
